# .txt to String with Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

The goal is simple. Grab some French text containing special characters from a .txt file and stick it into the variable "content". All is working well except that all instances of the character "à" are being interpreted as "À". Did I pick the wrong encoding (UTF7) or what?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Using ecoding to ensure special characters work
Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF7;

// Make sure we get all the information about special chars
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

// Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string. 
char[] fileChars = new char[enc.GetCharCount(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)];
enc.GetChars(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length, fileChars, 0);
string fileString = new string(fileChars);

 // Insert the resulting encoded string "fileString" into "content"
 content = fileString;
```

Comment: Have you tried utf8? its what most things use in my experience

Comment: UTF7 is likely wrong as it rarely used... But it can't be honestly answered because you MUST known correct encoding... Required reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Also, just use `File.ReadAllText`. It does everything you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct besides the wrong encoding. Find the correct one and plug it in. Nobody uses `UTF7` so this is probably not it.

Maybe it is a non-Unicode one. Try `Encoding.Default`. That one empirically often helps in Germany.

Also, just use `File.ReadAllText`. It does everything you are doing.